# Remove duplicate elements from HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have this HTML:

```
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='tab_5_data'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='tab_5_data'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='grid_1' id='grid_1_domType'>
```

In this screen you can see that class name is same, but their ids are different.

I write this to get all fields:

```
$(unescape(HtmlString)).filter(".allDomObjects").each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

This `.each()` loop runs 7 times, because 7 fields have 'allDomObjects' class. You can see there are duplicate elements in this string.

Requirement:

I want to remove duplicate elements from HTML string.

Input:

```
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='tab_5_data'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='tab_5_data'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='grid_1' id='grid_1_domType'>
```

Desired output:

```
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='grid_17_domType'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='' id='tab_5_data'>
<input type=hidden' class='allDomObjects' value='grid_1' id='grid_1_domType'>
```

Comment: And what issue are you experiencing with the code you've written towards this requirement so far?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this? We can use document.createElement and check for duplicates, But this is too much code and may be it's not good to write extra code when we achieve this by 2 or 3 lines. If i am not wrong we can do this by 'Regx' and LOC is about maximum 4 or 5 line.

Comment: Can you explain how you ended up in this situation in the first place? I just want to double-check that you are trying to fix the right end of the problem.

Comment: I am getting this string from my client's server via ajax, And i don't have permission to change there.

Comment: You have double ids. An id attribute value should be unique. You should address the problem *ex ante*, not after te fact.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's why I am trying to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use some map object to store ids:

```
var map = {};
$(unescape(HtmlString)).each(function() {
    if (map[this.id]) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
    else {
        map[this.id] = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not parse html with regex.its prone to errors.If you dont get a better solution you can try this.

```
<input\s+type=hidden'\s+class='allDomObjects'\s+value='[^']*'\s+id='([^']*)'>(?=.*?<input\s+type=hidden'\s+class='allDomObjects'\s+value='[^']*'\s+id='\1'>)
```

Put flags `g` and `s`.See demo.Replace by `empty string`.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/36

Answer (score 0):

try this. Remember you need to keep 1st element in all the duplicate so start the loop from 1

```
$(unescape(HtmlString)).filter(".allDomObjects").each(function() {
    if ( $('[id="'+this.id+'"]').length > 1 ) {
        for ( var i = 1; i < $('[id="'+this.id+'"]').length, i++ ) {
            $('[id="'+this.id+'"]')[i].remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please look at this line $('[id="'+this.id+'"]')[i].remove(); this will remove from DOM, Not from HTML string.

Comment: so in case if you have bind any events on id it will only be bind to the 1st element with this id also removing from html doesn't make sense keeping it in dom? no?